# unable to add reference to windows.media.speechsynthesis.dll

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, text-to-speech, system.windows.media

I am working on text to speech conversion in windows 8.1 (silverlight) and i need to access the `SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync` method for which I need to add reference to `Windows.media.speechSynthesis`. I am unable to add this reference to my project

it shows me error message as

> A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project.

I am currently using Visual studio 2013 professional version. Can someone please help me out with this issue?

Comment: Here is my code for this part


 private  void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SpeakText(audioPlayer, "Hello world");
        }

 private async void SpeakText(MediaElement audioPlayer, string TTS)
        {
            Windows.Phone.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer ttssynthesizer = new Windows.Phone.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();

            SpeechSynthesisStream ttsStream = await ttssynthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(TTS);

            audioPlayer.SetSource(ttsStream, "");
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechsynthesis.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), it is only supported in 8.1 XAML apps, not in 8.1 Silverlight apps.

Comment: thanks...
can you please suggest me some other methods for accessing the text to speech part in windows 8.1 silverlight moblie apps???

Comment: use Windows.Phone.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer